aws glue and jdbc connection(postgres) schema read options
From my aws glue pyspark script, I connected to postgres jdbc connection to read list of tables data (one list for dimensions ad one for facts tables).
pg_options = {}  # it has connection details
table_names = ['XYZ']
for table in table_names:
    pg_options['dbtable'] = f"""
        (SELECT *
         FROM {table}
         WHERE created_date > '{start_date_str}' AND created_date  < '{end_date_str}') AS data
    """
    df = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(**pg_options).load()
    df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").csv("file_name", header=True)

here I listed one table it will have many tables, currently i am seeing that in my csv which is writing to s3 the datatype of column is most of all are string (json data are there those were treating as string).
In pandas it reading correctly (I tested to check how schema is infered)
1. Can we read schema from tables or db or what i am seeing is the correct behavior
2. as I said there will be list of fact and dimension tables (both have different mechanism to read data from db like facts read daily and dimension read monthly (slow change)), what will best way at query and even to s3 i am writing with coalesce is that correct way
